# Programa que extraiga la extensión de un nombre de fichero introducido por el usuario en Python

Tags: python

Acabo de empezar con Python y no tengo nada de experiencia en programación. En un ejercicio del curso nos piden que escribamos este programa:

Escribe un programa que extraiga la extensión de un nombre de fichero introducido por el usuario.

El nombre de un fichero es una cadena de caracteres que puede tener una extensión, que es la sucesión de caracteres que van a continuación del último punto presente en la cadena. Asumiremos que si el nombre de fichero no contiene un punto, su extensión es la cadena vacía ''.

El problema es que no sé cómo hacer que se imprima una cadena vacía cuando no se añade la extensión con punto. Hasta ahora el código que tengo es este:

```
filename = input('Introduce el nombre del archivo: ')

extension = filename.split('.') [-1]
```

Comment: Probablemente no debas usar funciones de módulos pero para que amplias tu conocimiento puedes ver la función [splitext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)

Answer (score 0):

Pones un If verificando el largo del split

```
filename = input('Introduce el nombre del archivo: ')

filedata = filename.split('.')
if(len(filedata)>1):
    print(filedata[1])
else:
    print("(vacio)") # print("") #literalmente esto imprimiría una cadena vacía
```